# How to improve the segmentation of an image for the grabcut algorithm?

Tags: java, android, opencv, kotlin, image-processing

I am developing a kotlin application to remove the background from images. For this, I am using the grabcut together with the coordinates of the area of ​​interest of the region to be cut. The user marks the region with a rectangle, the coordinates are passed to the algorithm which in turn performs the background removal. However, the algorithm is unable to work well on some images and ends up removing regions where it did not need to be removed, as shown in the image below. How do I improve image segmentation for better grabcut performance?
[image]

Exit:

[image]

COde:

```
typealias Coordinates = Pair<Point, Point>
private fun extractForegroundFromBackground(coordinates: Coordinates, currentPhotoPath: String): String {

    // Matrices that OpenCV will be using internally
    val bgModel = Mat()
    val fgModel = Mat()

    val srcImage = Imgcodecs.imread(currentPhotoPath)
    val iterations = 5

    // Mask image where we specify which areas are background, foreground or probable background/foreground
    val firstMask = Mat()

    val source = Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8U, Scalar(Imgproc.GC_PR_FGD.toDouble()))
    val rect = Rect(coordinates.first, coordinates.second)

    // Run the grab cut algorithm with a rectangle (for subsequent iterations with touch-up strokes,
    // flag should be Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_MASK)
    Imgproc.grabCut(srcImage, firstMask, rect, bgModel, fgModel, iterations, Imgproc.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

    // Create a matrix of 0s and 1s, indicating whether individual pixels are equal
    // or different between "firstMask" and "source" objects
    // Result is stored back to "firstMask"
    Core.compare(firstMask, source, firstMask, Core.CMP_EQ)

    // Create a matrix to represent the foreground, filled with white color
    val foreground = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))

    // Copy the foreground matrix to the first mask
    srcImage.copyTo(foreground, firstMask)

    // Create a red color
    val color = Scalar(255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0)
    // Draw a rectangle using the coordinates of the bounding box that surrounds the foreground
    Imgproc.rectangle(srcImage, coordinates.first, coordinates.second, color)

    // Create a new matrix to represent the background, filled with white color
    val background = Mat(srcImage.size(), CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

    val mask = Mat(foreground.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar(255.0, 255.0, 255.0))
    // Convert the foreground's color space from BGR to gray scale
    Imgproc.cvtColor(foreground, mask, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    // Separate out regions of the mask by comparing the pixel intensity with respect to a threshold value
    Imgproc.threshold(mask, mask, 254.0, 255.0, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    // Create a matrix to hold the final image
    val dst = Mat()
    // copy the background matrix onto the matrix that represents the final result
    background.copyTo(dst)

    val vals = Mat(1, 1, CvType.CV_8UC3, Scalar(0.0))
    // Replace all 0 values in the background matrix given the foreground mask
    background.setTo(vals, mask)

    // Add the sum of the background and foreground matrices by applying the mask
    Core.add(background, foreground, dst, mask)

    // Save the final image to storage
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(currentPhotoPath + "_tmp.png", dst)

    // Clean up used resources
    firstMask.release()
    source.release()
    bgModel.release()
    fgModel.release()
    vals.release()
    dst.release()

    return currentPhotoPath
}
```